# YouTube not showing the names of the videos searched unless video is clicked, neither can be skipped to a certain time

Tags: youtube

I'm using a tablet, and the problem is that YouTube is not showing the name of the videos I've searched unless I click the video.

Also, whenever I watch a video I can't skip it to a certain time (the red bar in the bottom where you can skip the video to the end is missing for my YouTube).

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you provide the screenshot, and also the device model and the Android version?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to resolve this.
1. Reboot your device 
2. Your youtube app is outdated so one thing you could do is upddate the app